# Pandas: How to create userByItem pivot_table for all the items in the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Suppose, I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
User Item Rating
u1   i1   3
u2   i2   4
u3   i3   5
u4   i1   2
u5   i2   1
u5   i4   3
u1   i4   2
```

I have split the dataset into 2 parts,
Train Dataset:

```
User Item Rating
u1   i1   3
u2   i2   4
u3   i3   5
```

and Test Dataset:

```
User Item Rating
u4   i1   2
u5   i2   1
u5   i4   3
u1   i4   2
```

If I create 2 pivot_table from this 2 splited dataset using the following code:

```
 trainPivot = pd.pivot_table(trainData, values='Rating',
                                index=['User'], columns=['Item'])
 testPivot = pd.pivot_table(testData, values='Rating',
                                index=['User'], columns=['Item'])
```

Then the resulting pivot_tables would look something like this,for Train Data:

```
       I1      I2         I3
U1     3       Null       Null
U2     Null    4          Null
U3     Null    Null       5
```

For Test Data:

```
       I1      I2    I4      
U4     2       Null  Null   
U5     Null    1     3
```

But I want my pivot_tables to look like this, For Train Data:

```
       I1      I2         I3     I4
U1     3       Null       Null   Null
U2     Null    4          Null   Null
U3     Null    Null       5      Null
```

and for Test Data:

```
       I1      I2    I3    I4      
U1     Null    Null  Null  2
U4     2       Null  Null  Null   
U5     Null    1     Null  3
```

How can I achieve this in Pandas dataframe using pivot_table method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to add an item column if it isn't present.

I wasn't sure what `Null` was so I inserted `nan` to keep with the default pandas format.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = pd.DataFrame({
    'User': ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4', 'u5', 'u5', 'u1'],
    'Item': ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i1', 'i2', 'i4', 'i4'],
    'Rating': [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2]
})

train_data = data.head(3)
test_data = data.tail(4)

train_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    train_data, values='Rating', index=['User'], columns=['Item']
)
test_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    test_data, values='Rating', index=['User'], columns=['Item']
)

unique_items = data['Item'].unique()

for item in unique_items:
    if item not in test_pivot:
        test_pivot[item] = np.nan
    if item not in train_pivot:
        train_pivot[item] = np.nan

# If you want the columns sorted alphabetically
train_pivot = train_pivot.reindex_axis(sorted(train_pivot.columns), axis=1)
test_pivot = test_pivot.reindex_axis(sorted(test_pivot.columns), axis=1)
```

Results in the outputs:

`train_pivot`:

```
Item   i1   i2   i3  i4
User                   
u1    3.0  NaN  NaN NaN
u2    NaN  4.0  NaN NaN
u3    NaN  NaN  5.0 NaN
```

`test_pivot`:

```
Item   i1   i2  i3   i4
User                   
u1    NaN  NaN NaN  2.0
u4    2.0  NaN NaN  NaN
u5    NaN  1.0 NaN  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct an empty shell with the full index/column listing, and then "add" the train and test sets to the shell:

```
shell = (data
         .pivot_table(values='Rating', index='User', columns='Item')
         .astype(str)
         .replace(".*", np.nan, regex=True))

shell
Item  i1  i2  i3  i4
User                
u1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
u2   NaN NaN NaN NaN
u3   NaN NaN NaN NaN
u4   NaN NaN NaN NaN
u5   NaN NaN NaN NaN

shell.loc[train_pivot.index].add(train_pivot, fill_value=0)
Item   i1   i2   i3  i4
User                   
u1    3.0  NaN  NaN NaN
u2    NaN  4.0  NaN NaN
u3    NaN  NaN  5.0 NaN

shell.loc[test_pivot.index].add(test_pivot, fill_value=0)
Item   i1   i2  i3   i4
User                   
u1    NaN  NaN NaN  2.0
u4    2.0  NaN NaN  NaN
u5    NaN  1.0 NaN  3.0
```

Note: Using `data` from @Arda Arslan's nicely constructed example.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'User': ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4', 'u5', 'u5', 'u1'],
    'Item': ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i1', 'i2', 'i4', 'i4'],
    'Rating': [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2]
})
train_data = data.head(3)
test_data = data.tail(4)
train_pivot = pd.pivot_table(train_data, values='Rating', index=['User'], columns=['Item'])
test_pivot = pd.pivot_table(test_data, values='Rating', index=['User'], columns=['Item'])
```